# Visualforce: selectList in pageBlockSection?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I have a pageBlockSection with some inputFields in my VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Installation" > 
    <apex:inputField label="Label-1" value="..." />
    <apex:inputField label="Label-2" value="..." />
    <apex:inputField label="Label-3" value="..." />
    <apex:inputField label="Label-4" value="..." />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

It looks like:

```
Label-1 Input-1         Label-2 Input-2
Label-3 Input-3         Label-4 Input-4
```

Now I want to add a custom selectList between fields 2 and 3:

```
<apex:inputField label="Label-1" value="..." />
<apex:inputField label="Label-2" value="..." />

<apex:outputLabel value="List Label:"/>
<apex:selectList value="..." size="1"> 
    <apex:selectOptions value="..." /> 
</apex:selectList>

<apex:inputField label="Label-3" value="..." />
<apex:inputField label="Label-4" value="..." />
```

This puts the selectList at the top of my pageBlockSection (before Label-1), not in second row and first column between fields 2 and 3. I tried to put selectList in apex:pageblocksectionitem, but it doesn't make a difference.
How can I put the selectList between two other fields in a two column pageBlockSection?

Answer (score 3):

apex:pageBlockSection by formats apex:inputField and apex:outputField.

For any custom input, one should use [`apex:pageBlockSectionItem`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm) inside [apex:pageBlockSection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm).

An example below:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Installation" > 
    <apex:inputField label="Label-1" value="..." />
    <apex:inputField label="Label-2" value="..." />

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel value="List Label:"/>
        <apex:selectList value="..." size="1"> 
            <apex:selectOptions value="..." /> 
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:inputField label="Label-3" value="..." />
    <apex:inputField label="Label-4" value="..." />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

From documentation of [apex:pageBlockSectionItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm):

> A single piece of data in an  that takes up one
>   column in one row. An  component can
>   include up to two child components. If no content is specified, the
>   column is rendered as an empty space. If one child component is
>   specified, the content spans both cells of the column. If two child
>   components are specified, the content of the first is rendered in the
>   left, "label" cell of the column, while the content of the second is
>   rendered in the right, "data" cell of the column.